# Simple PHP Function Boolean Problem

Tags: php, function, boolean

Someone please explain to me why this doesn't work, and what I am doing wrong. For some reason, when I run the function `validateUsername`, the `$error` variable remains completely unchanged, instead of evaluating to `true`. How is this possible?

Yet, if I remove the code within the function and run it straight without a function call, it works. The example below is so simple it is practically pseudo code, and yet it doesn't work. Is this behavior unique to PHP? I don't want to run into this again in some other language.

```
<?php

$username = 'danielcarvalho';
$error = false;

function validateUsername()
{
    if (strlen($username) > 10)
    {
        $error = true;
    }
}

validateUsername();

if ($error == false)
{
    echo 'Success.';
}
else
{
    echo 'Failure.';
}

?>
```

Comment: Read up on variable scope: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: In addition to variable scope, also read up on returning values from functions

Comment: It's just in a function on the same page, surely this can't be a variable scope issue? Guess I'm wrong. I'll read up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't working because `$username` isn't available within the scope of your `validateUsername` function. (Neither is the `$error` variable.) See the [variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) section of the PHP manual for more information.

You could fix this by adding `global $username, $error;` within your function, although this isn't a particularly elegant approach, as global variables are shunned for reasons too detailed to go into here. As such, it would be better to accept `$username` as an argument to your function as follows:

```
<?php
    function validateUsername($username) {
        if (strlen($username) > 10) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    if (validateUsername('danielcarvalho')) {
        echo 'Success.';
    }
    else {
        echo 'Failure.';
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks chap, great answer. I'm still just struggling to cope with the fact that it is a scoping issue. Seems illogical / impractical to me.

Comment: @Daniel It might seem that way initially - but just think about it as trying to keep the "locality" of variables to an absolute minimum. (In other words, as a means of obtaining the highest level of separation/isolation, which is always a good thing as you'll discover when you encounter things like [object-oriented programming](http://www.php.net/oop).) Happy travels! :-)

Comment: To be fair though, I'm very experienced in ActionScript and have done a moderate amount of C#, and both of them never had this strict scoping issue where they can't see a variable declared just outside of a function.

Answer (score 1):

$error has local scope in function validateUsername. To access global variables, use global keyword.

Read about scopes [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). Change your function to:

```
function validateUsername($username)
{
    global $error;
    if (strlen($username) > 10)
    {
        $error = true;
    }
}
```

validateUsername($username);

Better implementation using function parameter:

```
function validateUsername($username, &$error)
{
    if (strlen($username) > 10)
    {
        $error = true;
    }
}
validateUsername($username, $error);
```

Another implementation:

```
function validateUsername($username)
{
    if (strlen($username) > 10)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
$error = validateUsername($username);
```

Comment: global variables aren't the answer to all the world's problems: they're likely to cause more problems than they solve, and aren't to be recommended when function arguments and return values are a more correct approach

Comment: @Ashwini Both of your solutions are a bit awry. In the first one, you need to use `&$error` in the function argument (otherwise, $error won't be updated in the "calling" scope) and I'd *really* avoid the needless use of a global as far as the second one is concerned.

Comment: Your second example will not work as expected - variables are passed by value by default, your global $error will not change whatever you do inside the function.

Comment: I voted you up for the detailed answer as well. Feels wrong not to award you with something. Hmmm, interesting comments though, will keep these concerns in mind.

Comment: @middaparka and Maelyn. Don't know how did I write it in first place! Have edited it.

Comment: @Ashwini Yup. There's still a `global $error;` in your second example, despite the fact that it's not touched within the function. Guessing it's just one of those days. :-)